# How to determine, if HTML element is generally visible? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Yes, I know: there are many questions like this, but I found no answer, which was working for me... :-(

I want to test, if an HTMLElement is generally (not just in the viewport) visible in an arbitrary webpage (I am writing a WebExtension).

Basically, if the user can spot that element by scrolling through the page, it should be evaluated as visible (true), otherwise as hidden (false).

**EDIT**: I changed following code, so that it is working for me so far:

```js
function isVisible(element) {
    if (element instanceof Text) return true;
    if (element instanceof Comment) return false;
    if (!(element instanceof Element)) throw Error("isVisible(): argument is not an element");
    
    // for real elements, the second argument is omitted (or null)
    // for pseudo-elements, the second argument is a string specifying the pseudo-element to match.
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(element, null);
    
    // if element has size 0
    if(element.offsetWidth === 0 || element.offsetHeight === 0){
        // only on 'visible', content does appear outside of the element's box 
        if (style.overflow !== 'visible') {
            return false;
        } else {
            for (let child of element.childNodes) {
                if (isVisible(child)) return true;
            }           
            return false;
        }
    }

    // if css display property is used
    if (style.display === 'none') return false;

    // if css visibility property is used
    if (style.visibility !== 'visible') return false;

    // if css opacity property is used
    if (parseFloat(style.opacity) === 0) return false;

    // this method does not work for elements with "position: fixed;"
    if (style.position !== 'fixed') {
        if (element.offsetParent === null) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If you see, that this code can be optimized, then please let me know! :-)

Comment: What is it about `<a-script>` that makes you think it should be classified as hidden?

Comment: Note: The last hack should be `elementsFromPoints( x, y ).includes(element)`

Comment: @Ouroborus You are right, the Inspektor does indeed highlight it. - But it shows the size of 0 x 20 for it and I can't see content from that element, that is why I like to detect it as invisible.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, for pointing out, that there is a second API available (btw: "Point" should be without a "s"), But this hack does not work for me, because all elements outside the viewport will be detect as invisible, even if they would be visible after scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

a-script is visible in a sense... You could check for the height and width of the element and if it's 0 then it's "hidden".

```
if(element.offsetWidth === 0 && element.offsetHeight === 0){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this idea in line 11. But I thought, that it is already invisible, if just one property is zero. That is important, because `<a-script>` is 0 x 20. And overflow setting should be considered too. But thanks for pointing out, to better use offsetWidth and offsetHeight.